# How to force Google Chrome to show backtrace on exception?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, backtrace

Is it possible (using plugin or maybe some config option) to make javascript error console to show error backtrace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's actually a button on Chrome's js console (looks like a pause button) that will give you this option.  It can be toggled to not pause on exceptions, pause only on unhandled exceptions, or pause on any exception.

Comment: I don't know how this got set on my work computer, but it has been annoying me for a couple weeks now. Do you know whether this has been changed to be enabled by default?

Comment: There are actually two things which look like pause buttons, and this one is the one on the right side "Pause On Caught Exceptions".